# Using eclipse PHP manual feature using drupal .inc

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, eclipse-pdt

So I notice that the Eclipse php manual feature (shift + F2) only works when the extension of the file I'm working on is .php

But then I'm using drupal and the file extensions are .inc even though they're still PHP code

Is there a way to configure eclipse such that the PHP manual feature will also work on .inc?

When I go to the manual settings page the only possible choices for the extension are php, html, and htm....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the eclipse file assocations by selecting Window -> Preferences, then in the new dialog navigate to General -> Content Types, in the right hand side expand the 'Text' content type and locate the 'PHP Content Type'.  Once there you can add the "*.inc" file association so that the built-in editor will treat `.inc` files as PHP.